# Why my api is not revalidating at certain amout of time in the new next router app directory?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

So, I want to retrive the data from my CMS to be able to show on my page. In Next.Js the cache is very aggresive, and I need to fetch the new data from my CMS into the page at certain time. I want to use `revalidate` function from Next.Js. As long as I use new app router, I cannot use `getStaticProps()` and I have to use the new way for the revalidate, so I find the documentation for it, but when I try to use `revalidate` function is not working, it's only working the cache option, like `{ cache: 'no-store' }` or `{ cache: 'relode' }` but I don't want to retrive the data at every single page reloade for performance point.

I use Sanity CMS, for any reference if you need this information.

Here is the `api/route` for my fetch:

```
export async function GET() {
  try {
    const query = groq`
    *[_type == "pageInfo"][0]
    `;
    
    const pageInfo: PageInfo[] = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

    return NextResponse.json({ pageInfo });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}
```

And here is my fetch function:

```
import { PageInfo } from "../typings";

export const fetchPageInfo = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/pageInfo`,
      { next: { revalidate: 10 } } // here the revalidation is supposed to work at every 10 seconds, but is not doing it
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      // Handle non-OK response (e.g., 404 or 500 error)
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data: ${res.status}`);
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    const pageInfo: PageInfo = data.pageInfo;

    // console.log("fetching", pageInfo);

    return pageInfo;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the fetch
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    return null; // Return a default value or handle the error as needed
  }
};
```

And here is how I call my function into my main component:

```
const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = useState(null);

    async function fetchData() {
      const pageInfo = await fetchPageInfo();
      setPageInfo(pageInfo); // Store pageInfo in state
    }
    fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it by setting an global revalidation to the `api/route` where I make the GET request.

> export const revalidate = 10;

Here is the code:

```
export const revalidate = 10; // here is the revalidation for my GET request

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const query = groq`
    *[_type == "pageInfo"][0]
    `;
    
    const pageInfo: PageInfo[] = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

    return NextResponse.json({ pageInfo });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}
```